# How to import mailbox module from python2.5 if I also have installed python2.6 and python3.1 on my machine?

Tags: python, importerror, python-2.5

I have a small problem with python and with the import of a module: I want to use the mailbox module from python2.5 but the problem is that I also have installed python2.6 and python3.1  on my machine and when the program reaches the line `import mailbox` the following error is raised (it`s only the final part of the error):
 `File "/usr/lib/python2.6/mailbox.py", line 19, in 
    import email.message
ImportError: No module named message`

How can I force the app to import the mailbox module from /usr/lib/python2.5?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: would you add python to the tags so other users can also answer?

Answer (score 0):

Run it using the appropriate executable.

```
python2.5 somescript.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working under windows and i do not know wether it is working under linux.

you may use .pth files that you can place somewhere you can import modules from.
if message.py is in a path called /usr/lib/python2.5/message.py you can use this pth file:

message.pth

```
/usr/lib/python2.5
```

place it somewhere from where you can import e.g. /usr/lib/python2.6 or /usr/lib/python3.1